# CSS `first of type` for elements that aren't siblings

Tags: html, css, sass

My markup looks like bellow:

```
<div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the `first-of-type` selector to hide the first h4 tag or each combined selector `.title.blue` and `.title.green`.

I think this isn't working because the elements aren't siblings. Is there a way to still use `first-of-type`?

[There's a pen as an example here](https://codepen.io/jamesjohnson94/pen/ybZjYy)

```css
h4.title.blue:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. _"I'm trying to use the first-of-type selector to hide the first h4 tag or each combined selector `.title.blue` and `.title.green`"_  - _all_ of your h4 match either `.title.blue` or `.title.green` -
 so what, you want them all gone?

Comment: Change markup: add a class to container like `blue` or `green` and make them silbings. Otherwise javascript is needed.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the first blue, and the first green one you should edit both your `html` and `CSS`. Take a look at the example below:

```css
h4.title:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

In this first example you can see that with the `first-child` selector each `<h4>` tag dissapears. This happens because they aren't on the same level. See the written example below:

```
- container
 - title container
  - h4
 - </title container
- </container
- container
 - title container
  - h4
 - </title container
- </container>
- container
 - title container
  - h4
 - </title container
- </container>
- container
 - title container
  - h4
 - </title container
- </container>
```

as you can see each `<h4>` tag is in a new container. So if i would use `CSS` like the following:

```
.container .title-container h4.title:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

it wouldn't display the first `<h4>` tag of each container. Since every container only has one they'll all dissapear.

As a solution try the following:

```css
.container .title-container h4.title:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue 1</h4>
        <p>Something blue no 1</p>
        <h4 class="title blue">blue 2</h4>
        <p>Something blue no 2</p>
    </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green 1</h4>
        <p>Something green no 1</p>
        <h4 class="title green">green 2</h4>
        <p>Something green no 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that answer and this does help but unfortunately, I can't change any markup.

Comment: @JamesJohnson So you're not able to change the `<html>` only the `CSS`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
h4.title:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

You should update css

```
h4.title:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That would hide all of the h4 tags. I only want to hide the first blue one and the first green one.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to use the first-of-type selector to hide the first h4 tag
>   or each combined selector .title.blue and .title.green.

You're almost there.

You need to use `:nth-of-type` on an element higher up the DOM.

**Working Example:**

```css
div > div:nth-of-type(odd) > div h4 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title blue">blue</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something blue no 2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
        <h4 class="title green">green</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Something green no 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to do this in the end. I wasn't able to change any markup but I could move CSS classes around.

I used `.container > .class-to-hide ~ .class-to-hide` as my selector. This selected all but the first elements of `.class-to-hide`.

[Here's a pen showing that](http://codepen.io/jamesjohnson94/pen/ybZjYy)